# There should be a minimum time between placing and accepting a bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, gaming-the-system

I wasn't sure it was possible, but last night I tested it out.  You can place a bounty and then immediately accept an answer for that question.

**Purpose of Bounties**

The primary function of the bounty system is to:

- Feature a question so it doesn't have to be bumped repeatedly
- Give people an additional incentive to add new and perhaps more comprehensive answers

I would also argue that a secondary function exists: provide other users an opportunity to gain a significant amount of reputation for a thorough and comprehensive or deeply researched answer (as generally the questions are hard to answer, or require special expertise or knowledge).  This is a particular help to those that don't have much time to spend daily on answering smaller questions.

**Problem**

As implemented, though, it *can* be used without the top two benefits, and disallowing others the opportunity to provide a better answer by starting a bounty and immediately accepting it.

Further, as an accepted answer with a bounty cannot be changed, it should require additional consideration.

Worse, it is possible that it may be considered gaming the system, or provide people a way to engage in other undesirable behavior.

**Proposal**

- Disallow acceptance of a bounty until 24 hours after it was started.

While some might use this functionality to provide an 'extra' reward to a particularly good answer, that answer will still be there in a day, so it won't prevent this functionality.  It should only affect those that seek to short circuit the purpose of the bounty.

Comment: Related, er, "testing" of the system... yeah: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery

Comment: looks like you gave away about 5k of rep last night... Madame Philanthropist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery/42583#42583) implemented?

> we are adding a 1-day delay between
>   the time a bounty starts and when it
>   can be awarded.

Answer (score 5):

As [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery/42583#42583) has said on another question (and [S.Mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/there-should-be-a-minimum-time-between-placing-and-accepting-a-bounty/43649#43649) in this one), there's now a 1-day delay between when a bounty starts and when it can be awarded.

Answer (score 4):

I agree completely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fine with this. Bounties have special rules, including that an accepted answer to a question with a bounty can't be changed - probably worth encouraging users to put some extra thought into their choice...

Alternately, allow users to accept whenever they like, but don't *apply* the bounty for 24 hours - and let the user change (revoke, move to another answer) their acceptance during that 24-hour timespan. Essentially, a grace period, such as exists for many other actions on SO.

Comment: I have to say I don't like your second paragraph. That just complicates things unnecessarily, I think.

Comment: @mmyers: probably; just figured I'd throw it out there because I like grace periods.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that bounties should encourage extra consideration for selection - I've incorporated that into the question.  I'm not a big fan of grace periods though.  Either the answer is featured immediately, garners some interest for a day, then the bounty is pulled, or it isn't featured for the grace period, which delays getting featured, and possibly delays getting a perhaps ASAP-ish answer.