# FAQ: update? Reputation is never given, Yet you get given reputation from bounty awards?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was just wondering if this sounds wrong:

> Reputation is never given, it is earned by convincing fellow users that you know what you’re talking about.

But when you get bounty awards you are given reputation from the user whom submitted the bounty?
Define: Giving

> To give what you have to another, in this case they are giving reputation to who ever answers it in time or gets accepted.

Can someone please fill in my blanks here as I am a little confused here? :)

Comment: The word "except" seems to be missing. :)

Comment: Does a question require_once "except" ?? for more they use just require :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is natural, as what you've seen *appears* to contradict itself.

However, the truth is simple: bounties are an abomination unto SO, a concession by The Powers That Be to the evil and greed in men's hearts. Originally, there were no bounties. One man, one vote. But folks wanted them. They wanted them *bad*...

**Moral of the story:** be careful what you beg and plead for...

Comment: How is there a conflict? where?

Comment: @JamesM: The FAQ states that reputation is never given. Which is how it works. Except for bounties, where reputation *is* given. The FAQ is... *Mostly* right, except for that *one glaring exception.*

Comment: Do you think someone who has access to the FAQ (for editing) should update it to something else??

Comment: @James: probably not. Again, the statement is *mostly* correct, and the purpose of the FAQ isn't to serve as exhaustive legal documentation. Think of it as a form of [lies we tell to children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children)

Comment: @Shog9: Wait, you're not telling me that Santa isn't real!??!?

Comment: @Mehrdad: oh, no, he's real enough... Just not as nice as they make him out to be in the stories.

Comment: @Shog9: phew... almost shattered all my dreams and beliefs there, lol ;)

Answer (score 4):

It appears to me it's merely an issue of interpretation.

```
Reputation is never given, it is earned by 
convincing fellow users that you know 
what you’re talking about.
```

I'd say that bounty reputation is earned by convincing the person who set the bounty that you know what you're talking about.

Comment: It can't be earned if they give it to you :P Earning means that the one who set the bounty lost no reputation, Bounty after a question has been answered is called donations :) Donations are giving. Bounties are giving.

Comment: @JamesM `Earn: to receive as return for effort and especially for work done or services rendered` So I'd say that bounties can be earned, even if given after the fact.  If someone gives a particularly exceptional answer to my work, and I place a bounty on it with the intent to give to that person, then as far as I'm concerned they earned it, even though they were willing to do that much work with little remuneration.  But perhaps you are trying to draw a much finer distinction than I understand.  When I do work for a client, I have earned payment that they give to me because I did the work.

Comment: @JamesM Of the many definitions of give, one is `to yield possession of by way of exchange; sell` perhaps you are thinking of give in terms of `to make a present of` So the question you pose above is merely semantics.  It is not grammatically incorrect, nor does it pose an illogical problem, given the definitions of the words used.  However, it could be interpreted as being illogical if one *chooses* to use alternate definitions for the words used.

Comment: @Pollyanna: I suspect he's getting caught up on the "never given" portion - while you may certainly earn a bounty, it *must* be given (well, sorta; there's still the whole "auto-award" feature to make this just that much more complex, but...)

Comment: Humm, @Pollyanna : okay I understand. lol you have the reputation to do so, thats like a rich man giving a little to the poor. :) Some people are too busy programming, to be online helping 24/7 :(

Comment: @JamesM Well, honestly, I'm the last person to be talking about earning reputation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery