# Existing answers should be eligible for bounty auto-award, when the reason for bounty is to reward an existing answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties, expired-bounty

I am not asking...

- ... to [remove the 24-hour waiting period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/251274) for reward-type bounties.
- ... for the [ability to pre-select](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158051/251274) the winning answer, either.

My request is this:

> When a user sets a bounty to reward an existing answer, existing answers should be eligible for auto-award of the bounty.

It makes no sense to deny eligibility to the answers that the user explicitly wanted to reward.

---

**An Example**: Math.SE currently has three 500-point bounties set by a departed user, with the stated reason "reward existing answer". They are set to questions with outstanding and very thorough answers. However, those answers will not receive bounty now, because the originating account has been deleted. The bounties are still there, owned by Community and subject to auto-award rules.

Comment: Personally, I think if I want to award a bounty to an existing answer, I should be able to just do so immediately. I understand that's not the true intention of the bounty, but if I just want to reward an answer that already sufficiently answers the question, it's not because I feel the question needs more attention.