# Is it possible to get all one's questions and answers deleted because of stalking?

Tags: discussion

If one is in threat of life because of being stalked, could one ask for deletion of all answers and questions? I don't mean simply removing the username; that is not enough.

Questions sometimes indirectly provide personal information that can lead to being identified, and it is impractical to read all posted content again, searching for such information (for example, questions and answers that cite previous works, or link to sites that allow identification). So posts are not really anonymous, and hence there's the need for deleting all user history. Would there be a monetary charge for this deletion? Is it possible?

Comment: I posted questions which contained material regarding some sects and cults, I don't think apprentices of those cults would be happy of those posts.

Comment: If you're so paranoid, turn off the computer, throw away any mobile device, cut off electricity, and you'll be (almost) safe.

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't just have all of your content deleted because you want to.

If you actually have some personally identifying information in a post of yours you can edit it out, replacing it with some suitable placeholder (if necessary) and you can flag a mod to remove it from the revision history.

Comment: That's not a maintanable solution. Especially if you have plenty of lenghty posts. a SQL query would be just much more feasible (Even paying)

Comment: @DarioOO Well, it's the only option available to you.

Comment: @DarioOO the key phrase is *personally identifying information*.  Moderators won't redact everything you ever said that you might now regret, but if you identify *specific* things that identify you, you can ask for redaction of those.  I would expect that to be a short list.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can *request* deletion of all of your posts, including the user name. Deletion here would mean hiding it from the majority of the community. Only 10K users can see deleted posts.

Whether that request would be honored is a question I can't answer. It is up to moderators or Stack Exchange employees to decide and will depend heavily on the information you provide to them. SE is in no way obligated to honor your request since you have given away the content under the CC-by-SA license.

Moderators are also capable of removing personal information from posts without leaving too much information to the outside world. This could be a solution that doesn't have such a big impact as deletion and has also the benefit of not being visible to 10K users.

Of course, all of this clear out the cache at Google and others, so if it is there, there is nothing SE can do.

Comment: You can request that SE give you a million dollars for no reason, but it'll never happen.  Why tell him to make a request that will never be granted?

Comment: Well, it *is* an option, in case of a real threat of course. I have also given the better solution, but the first part actually answers the question.

Comment: Telling them that they can make a request that will never be granted isn't an answer.  He asked if he can have all of his content removed, not just personally identifying content.  He can't.

Comment: Not really. One can't ask to delete all their posts, and trying to delete own posts just for sake of deletion would lead to suspension.

Comment: Hey Patrick, can you please take a look on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158051/automatic-award-of-bounty-after-it-expired-for-pre-existing-question-when-the) and the comments? It was closed as duplicate years ago, OP realized it just now and claiming it's not a dupe. Already used my reopen vote to clean up, what do you think?

Answer (score -1):

As advised by others, the most important thing for you to do is erasing all the personal information you mistakenly posted by contacting moderators.

> Questions sometimes indirectly provide anyway personal information for being identified...

It's your own responsibility and you are the one who should be careful not to give any personal information.

> So posts are not really anonymous and hence there's the need for deleting all user history.

If you delete you account on any SE site, your user (display) name will be changed to *user number xyz* and you don't have to worry about revealing your identity.

> Would that cost anything? How much?

Stack Exchange is free of charge for every single service except for advertising and jobs. There is no cost at all.

Comment: While not particularly relevant to this case, Stack Exchange does have paid services, like advertising and jobs.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Valid point. Edited my answer.