# Change the description of the exemplary answer bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

So in this question [Should the 24-hour timeout apply to bounties awarded for "exemplary answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) the removal of the 24 hour time limit was denied (incorrectly imo)

But I'm not going to argue that (this is meta), instead the description should be changed to show that the bounty is also to get more people to view the question as is natural with other bounties. When I chose the bounty I fully expected to be able to award it straight away! So it should more clear to the sure making the choice.

Also the description it adds to the question doesn't give the indication that more answers are wanted (and I don't want more answers to my question it's answered perfectly by the existing 2 answers) but it seems thats what it's for according to the linked meta question above.

So the description should be changed (or preferably the time limit removed, but that is below secondary to my point about the description)