# Awarding a bounty

Tags: support, answers, bounties

I got excellent answer to my question and I want to award a bounty for this answer. How should I do this?

Just to make sure that I am clear. I created several bounties before. However, I created all of them PRIOR receiving answers. So, awarding a bounty was a matter of clicking on this bounty sign under a vote counter.

Situation is different now, because I don't have active bounty. However, I want to award a bounty for excellent answer.

One more piece of information. I feel that somebody will comment right now, that if the answer is so great, other users will upvote it. This is not the case, because it was quite specialized question and answer in very small tag. So, I don't think that it will get enough attention.

Answer (score 6):

The procedure is the same; just add a bounty to your question, and pick the `Reward existing answer` option:

[image: existing answer option]

You get to reward it after an initial waiting period (24 hours).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice it before. BTW. Why does it have 24 hours waiting period. It doesn't make too much sense for a "Reward existing answer" option.

Comment: @VictorRonin it is a blanket rule. Nothing to do with the reason for the bounty

Comment: @VictorRonin: If the 24-h rule did not apply to that option, it'd be abused to transfer rep instantly. It'd be a bypass to the rate limitation.

Comment: @VictorRonin there is, for better or worse, a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) to remove the wait for this bounty reason.

Comment: @Rory: That feature request never stood a chance. It would let you bypass the limits by using a bogus reason otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Just make the bounty.

Then assign it to the answer when you can.

Easy as π