# Reward a bounty If reason is to reward existing answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to award a bounty to an existing answer, should I have to wait 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours)

Today, I wanted to award an answer of a question that sounded very cool to me and I started a bounty on it and I selected the proper reason for starting a bounty. But when I clicked on blue number, it said I have to wait 23 hours. I think it's something of a waste of time to have to wait.