# Disable cooldown for bounties marked with "I want to reward an existing answer"

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to award a bounty to an existing answer, should I have to wait 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours)

The title speaks for itself.
I've read **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5863870/871050)** question, and its answers, and I would like to award a bounty on one of them, as a reward for the awesome content that answer has.

Since I've already read the answer, and I know it's the correct one and is the one I would like to award, why should I need to wait a full day before I can award the bounty?

Can we have a workaround?

Comment: +1 I had the same problem 2 days ago.

Comment: @TimStone: Just when I thought I had something original. CVed.