# how to award a bounty(+50) instantly

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I want to award +50 for the user who answered my question.
Do I need to start a bounty and after 24 hours offer it? 
Or can I just offer +50 instantly? 
(I had not start a bounty on the question)

Comment: The reason you can't do that is that other users should have a chance at that bounty as well. If you start a bounty and someone else writes an even better answer, they should have a legitimate chance at earning that bounty.

Comment: Isn't there an option to reward an existing answer? I think it should give the bounty immediately to the answerer.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes there is, what you say was [asked and declined already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I never used the bounty system so I don't know, but it seems like a nice answer to this question than the answer below. Another possible dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot award a bounty instantly. See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty.

This is because if you start a bounty, there is a chance you will get a better answer. Then you can give the bounty to that answer instead. Of course, if that doesn't happen, just give the bounty to the answer you had in mind.

This is actually a good thing. Wouldn't you rather have a better answer than the answer you have right now?