# Paragraph breaks in bounty reasons not displayed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks)
>   [Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text)

I have just offered a bounty on [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions), in which I gave a rather detailed reason for the bounty.

I formatted my reason with paragraph breaks for readability, which I especially thought would work because of the long (2500?) character limit and because the return key did not automatically submit the form.

However whilst the HTML still contains the newlines that I entered, they have not been converted to paragraph breaks; was this intentional, or is it an oversight?

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks for that link.  I have removed my final paragraph and updated the title to keep the question focused on paragraph breaks, as I don't think that's addressed in the other question.

Comment: In the other post the dev said "using the same format as we allow for comments" - and in comments we don't have paragraphs. :)

Comment: Still a dupe: *using the same format as we allow for comments*. Hence, no line breaks.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: True.  But then, in comments hitting the return key causes the comment to be submitted; and comments are restricted to being much shorter!  Perhaps paragraph breaks *should* be allowed in bounty reasons, even if they are currently not by design?

Comment: Maybe so, in this case you might try and ask for a feature request. :)

Comment: @Arjan nice, didn't see this one before.