# Adding a bounty to a great question

Tags: support, questions, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions)

Is there a way to award a bounty to a user who posted a great question, other than adding the bounty to one of his answers?

Comment: Not directly. Upvote of course and share it with other people.

Comment: Related: [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135469)

Comment: A great answer is the reward for a great question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. If you're determined to somehow award the asker for his excellent question, however, you can open a bounty on his question. While the asker won't directly receive the reputation for the bounty you set, it will help him in the following ways:

1. Increases the chances he will receive a quality answer. Normally, this is all the asker of a good question desires.
2. Increased exposure to the question will earn him additional upvotes, which will increase his reputation. That is if nearly everyone holds the same opinion about his question as you do, of course.
3. His question view count will increase, which could potentially lead to a badge.

Alternatively, you could go around the office, telling all your coworkers about this amazing question you found while you were supposedly working. Or perhaps send out an email to all your relatives, only a handful of whom are in career fields anywhere remotely related to computers. You could even make your website automatically redirect all users to the superb question.

Seriously, though, all a good question deserves is a good answer. Any additional reputation or badges are mere extras. If you're incapable or providing that good answer yourself, you can start a bounty on the question to tempt a more experienced user to do so.