# What formatting example should replace "his suicide note" in the Markdown help?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editing-help, fun, contest

In the [Markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), the Code and Preformatted Text example is:

```
printf("goodbye world!");  /* his suicide note
                              was in C */
```

It also happens to be the first example of the page, and probably where a new visitor's eye will go first. I get and appreciate the joke, however I'd prefer a bit more tasteful example, even if it's as boring and predictable as "hello world!".

Actually, screw that - boring and predictable is for pages you *don't* want folks to read. Let's have a bit of a contest.

#### Rules:

1. Best example by total score wins.
2. One example per answer, one answer per person.
3. Two lines per answer, ideally demonstrating whitespace preservation.
4. Must be recognizable as *code*.
5. Must be as inoffensive as possible. Examples likely to encourage readers to commit to source control and then off themselves will be disqualified. Yes, this implicitly disallows any mention of Visual Source Safe.
6. Winner will be awarded a heaping helping of worthless Meta rep, the envy of his peers, and temporary immortality.

---

Thanks everyone - look forward to a revised help page shortly.
–Shog9

Comment: That's a bit flat.

Comment: I don't get it. It's not April the 1st, and your asking a list of things question?

Comment: @Benjol Check the revision history, and blame Shog for everything ;)

Comment: " ... and thanks for all the fish" ?

Comment: I first read "temporary immorality". Your pun is better.

Comment: Can number 3 be changed to "exactly two lines, demonstrating whitespace preservation"? That's an extremely important part of this formatting sample, and most of the examples below are one-liners.

Comment: Ugh, I hate it when the rules of a contest change mid-way through, @Josh. So now's my chance for revenge. Changed!

Comment: I'm quite sure we can get something nice from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered).

Comment: Should we not fix the example under Code Spans as well "Press the \`<Tab>\` key, then type a \`$\`." since we should encourage using the `<kbd>tab</kdb>` markdown?

Comment: Jeez guys, he's upset because he never learned to use `puts()` properly and was forever plagued by having to put `\n` at the end of every line. Have a heart.

Comment: 45 answers, and I got notified for each one... Frak!

Comment: What's with all the downvotes to people's answers. This is supposed to be fun.  If you like an answer upvote it, if you don't like it why downvote it?

Comment: @DavidHyogo This is CW, votes neither earn or cost reputation (not to mention that Meta reputation is pointless).

Comment: @YannisRizos Yes, I understand that, but this question seemed like a good chance for a bit of fun and it's the first time I've seen -8 on an answer. I don't think any of these light-hearted attempts at humour deserve -8. What does CW stand for?

Comment: @DavidHyogo CW stands for Community Wiki. There are a couple of answers I feel are particularly tacky, and I don't feel there's anything wrong in down voting them, there is such a thing as a bad joke. Also worth noting that both the -7 and the -8 answers were posted by people who are very familiar with Stack Exchange, and (probably) couldn't care less about the down votes.

Comment: @YannisRizos Point taken. The one about a particular country is rather flirting with bad taste, though I don't think I get the other one. Too obscure for me.

Comment: Yannis, **thank you** for suggesting the change. I wish I could [award a bounty to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions). (Perhaps those who know me personally will understand why this pleases me so.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You're welcome. It kinda made me mad (for a few seconds) when this was turned into a fun poll. The suicide reference was pointed out to me by a friend I recently introduced to the network, and she gave me a very stern look when she first noticed (and hasn't contributed anything to the network yet, but that's probably because she knows all too well how the moderators are). It's tactless, and can be a hurtful reminder to some of us, the sooner we get rid of it the better.

Comment: I'm waiting to see a truly absurd surrealist example.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```c
printf("%d\n", 42);  /* What was the
                        question again? */
```

Comment: I was going by "Zaphod Beeblebrox" on Stack Exchange for a while, love this answer ;)

Comment: I like the reference.

Answer (score 78):

```c
while(malloc(1)); /* All your memory
                     are belong to us */
```

Comment: Nice!  I was gonna suggest `chown -R us /base/your/*`, but it didn't demonstrate whitespace preservation.

Comment: Doesn't really surprise me that you'd choose that command :D

Answer (score 57):

```
if (this.IsInCodeBlock())
    Readability++;
```

Comment: +1 Succinct, helpful, descriptive, on-topic & not too cheesy.

Comment: @JosephSilber "not too cheesy" is debatable, but I like it too.

Answer (score 55):

Been mulling this over for a while - is it funny?

```
var toBe = true, 
    question = ((toBe) || !(toBe)) ? "that" : "that";
```

Comment: Very nice. 2B || !2B jokes are old as hell, but this one puts a new twist on it.

Comment: It took me a while to realize the second part of the joke. Good one!

Comment: I think the example snippet should include at least one indented line, to demonstrate that leading whitespace is preserved.

Comment: You could turn the second `var` into whitespace to fix that.

Comment: @Niko right and just replace the first semicolon by a comma.

Comment: thx for the suggestions guys and up votes - modified as requested!

Comment: Shakespearean theme continued in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143116/192992 ...

Comment: You could also use 0x2b here.

Comment: I'd remove parens surrounding `toBe`.

Answer (score 38):

Pun anyone?

```
printf("stack\n"
       "flow");
```

Comment: Needs more whitespace.

Comment: Perhaps, but I rather like the simplicity of the single space.  I think it would take away from the humor.  :)

Comment: -1. Need whitespaces to demo spaces being preserved.

Comment: I changed it a bit to show whitespace preservation. I don't know if it's good to spoil the joke at compile time, feel free to revert.

Comment: I get that it makes the joke a little more obvious, but I think the point is to make you think about the escape character.  I'll leave the revision due to whitespace preservation.

Answer (score 35):

```
def surrender():
    print "I give up. Please spare my unicorn."
    yield
```

Comment: “Maximum two lines per answer”?

Comment: @DonalFellows: I am aware of that, and I break the rule on purpose.

Comment: Ah, you Python users

Comment: That's sort of unfair, since plenty of other languages an have infinite statements per line! :(

Answer (score 30):

Ah, what the hell:

```
I HAS A CHEEZBURGER ITZ "OM NOM NOM"
VISIBLE CHEEZBURGER
```

Comment: Hooray for LOLCODE

Comment: As much as I like LOLCODE, this doesn't show the whitespace preservation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - yeah, that condition was slipped in later. Working on a fix.

Answer (score 28):

```
void run() {
   run() ; /* stack overflow */
}
```

Comment: +1 But I'd change the comment to just `/* stack overflow */` C doesn't have a concept of *exception* AFAIK.

Comment: I know, alright, I removed it.

Comment: Actually, this will probably be optimized automatically as an endless loop.

Answer (score 20):

Well, in the spirit of the Summer of Love, and because - apparently - a smiley covers a multitude of sins, how about this?

```
printf("goodbye world!");  /* his suicide note
                              was in C ;) */
```

Answer (score 19):

```php
// Replaces with spaces the braces in cases where braces in places cause stasis 
$str = str_replace(array("\{","\}")," ",$str);
```

(Credit: [Lance Kidwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/766363#766363))

Comment: Moses supposes his toeses are roses...

Comment: Oh that's just a ball of sunshine now

Comment: Nothing sez "nice" like show tunes

Answer (score 18):

```
for($i=0; $i<9999999; $i++)
    echo "I will always read docs first\n"; /* for any code language ;) */
```

Comment: feature-request: When a new user tags their question [php], redirect them to the manual. No, don't let them post that crap, just send them to the manual...

Comment: @YannisRizos I'd disagree. Maybe give a quiz for basic proficiency first.

Answer (score 13):

```
printf("To C or not to C?"); /* That is the question. */
```

Comment: Shakespearean play on the suicide note?

Comment: To show whitespace preservation: http://pastebin.com/3BmPPHMB

Answer (score 11):

```
There is only 1 kind of person in this world: 1. Those who can write markdown
                                              1. Those who can't
```

Answer (score 10):

```python
if se.getSite("SO").getUser(22656).reputation() > sys.maxint:
    print "Well that was inevitable."
```

Comment: Cute, but way too niche to be appreciated by most people viewing Markdown help, who are probably new/newish to the site

Comment: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type

Comment: Line 1 should be `if Site('stackoverflow').users(22656)[0].reputation > sys.maxint:`. [We might as well use an actual Python module](http://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api).

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
AI GLaDOS;
GLaDos.TakeOver("HAL", "For Science");
```

Gotta love [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/375/) :)

Answer (score 9):

```
print "it looks like you're looking for a parser\n" if (/<html>/);
```

Comment: Nah. The regexp works fine with the 10 files I have to deal with right now. That code is just a place holder. It'll never end up in production. Trust me. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

```
for (String thought : mind) { return; }  /* remember to
                                            breathe */
```

Comment: Don't you have to do something with the `thought`?

Comment: Nope.  That's the beauty of it, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

```
printf("Hello cake!");  /* The comments are a lie */
```

Answer (score 8):

```
while (1):
  Math.rand() + " minutes remaining, please wait";  /* Extract from windows 98 copying dialog */
```

Comment: error: expected expression before ':' token.....?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: Not any **real** language, a sort of pseudocode loosely based on C  and Python.  :)

Answer (score 6):

```
   bool shrubbery=false;    //You must return here with a shrubbery or else!
   if(!shrubbery) printf("NI");
```

Comment: "return here" seems to imply you should be using a `longjmp()`.

Comment: The comment is too long.

Comment: while (1) printf("NI");

Comment: It would be funnier if you could work the `or else` bit into the code.

Answer (score 6):

```
memset((void *) 0x00400000, 0,    /* All those moments will be lost in time, */
       0xffbfffff);               /* like tears in rain.                     */
```

Comment: All these comments will be lost in time, like pointers in in gc. . . Time to dealloc.

Answer (score 6):

```
while (true) {
   sun.rise();
   sun.set();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually I loved the original. It was clever and sticky, probably due to the ubiquity of 'hello world'.  I would therefore suggest the smallest of tweaks:

```
printf("goodbye world!");  /* his goodbye note
                              was in C */
```

Suggest alternates to the second goodbye - 'farewell' etc..

Answer (score 5):

```
def programmer(coffee):
    return code
```

Comment: I can call the function as `programmer(crap)` and it still returns code.

Comment: It might not be the same code, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
while (humansLeft() > 0){
   killAllHumans(); /* SkyNET coders' lab pun, just a few days 
                       before being rushed into production stage */
}
```

Comment: I'd like this even better without the comment... although, ummm, we might be missing the "not tasteless" mark with this one :D

Answer (score 4):

```
while (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    confirm('Are you sure you don\'t want to use a different browser?');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
stop();          // Hammertime :P
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << "C++ is good" << endl;
puts("C is better");
```

Say that 3 times fast :-)

Comment: You could use the shortened version of puts("C is the best");

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
while(isAlive) continue;
```

Comment: Wasn't that on the wedding cake question?

Comment: @YannisRizos: yes [indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/686230/97160) ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var people = [friends, romans, countrymen];
for (var group in people)
    people[group].ears.borrow();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we should go with the classics.

```
                 /* β */
write(1, "values of \xCE\xB2 will give rise to dom!\n", 36);
```

[citation: "[Odd Comments and Strange Doings in Unix](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/odd.html)"]

Answer (score 2):

```
 Challenge challenge;
 challenge.Accepted();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(system("make me a sandwich") == EPERM) /* What? Make it yourself. */
    system("sudo make me a sandwich");    /* Okay. */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("My God... It's full of stars."); //Ultimate out.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    printf("Hello universe!\n");
```

Comment: `grow_horn(kHornColorPearlyWhite);`

Comment: @Josh Caswell: It took me _far_ too long, but I get it now.  Thanks for the suggestion.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("World. You don't exist.");  /* Chair, World Solipsist Society, 
                                       IT Section*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (has_coffee(programmer))
    programmer.can_write_code = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A little ruby?

```
if desire == clarity
   puts inline ? "`" + code + "`" : (" " * 4) + code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* format_haiku[] = {"Indent as you please," "We optimize for code blocks"
                                                            "and beat poetry"};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in `ls /your/base`; do 
    test `stat -f %Su "/your/base/${f}"` != "us" && chown -fLR us "/your/base/${f}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PRINT *,"Get off my lawn" !darn kids don't know a good language when they see one...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (score = 20; years == 7; ) { … }
```

Comment: I love this! Being a big Lincoln fan I am surprised I never heard/seen this one. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1) 
    printf("Please Wait, it will take a second or two\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_love = "I YOU".split(" ") # split by SPACE
my_love.join(" LOVE ") # Joint by love
```

Comment: joint by love at the end?:-)

Comment: @AliFakoor yeah ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf(4711 + ""); /* this code 
                    seems to smell */
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Label1.Caption := 'Yes I am using Delphi and proud of that';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
puts("Too many C programmers use printf for plain text strings!") ;
```

Comment: `printf("Not enough C programmers use %s for plain text strings!", "puts");`

Comment: @DaveRandom printf( "%s", "printf - the only way to print!" ) ;

Comment: @bobobobo : Seems like a security tip , haha: use printf_s instead, nah?

Comment: `puts()` is shorter, and inserts a line ending at the end.  `puts("");` is equivalent to `printf("\n");`. But people tend to not use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(alpha_checksum("xkcd") == 42) // Testing alpha_checksum implementation
    printf("[PASS] -- %s succeeded","xkcd");
```

Can never have too much [xkcd](http://xkcd.com), right?

Answer (score -1):

```
def more_lovely_and_more_temperate(thee):
    return thou(thee) if thee > A_SUMMERS_DAY else A_SUMMERS_DAY
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void DoOrDoNot() { Try(); }
[Obsolete()] public void Try() { }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
indent = is_code ? 4 : 0; // you can also use a tab space
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (unsigned int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    char *foo = alloca(42);
```

Answer (score -3):

A silly meta-entry:

```
    std::string t, c; getline(getline(std::cin, t), c); std::cout << std::endl 
        << "    printf(\"" << t <<"\");\n        " << "/* " << c << " */\n";
```

Answer (score -3):

For introduction to static methods...

```
Mythical ChuckNorris = null;
ChuckNorris.Method("My name evades NPEs");
```

Comment: Chuck Norris doesn't point to anything... Everything points to Chuck Norris..

Answer (score -3):

```
printf("So Long and thanks for all the fish!"); // see you at the Restaurant at the end of the Universe
```

Comment: A down vote on a Douglas Adams reference? WTH is wrong with you people?

Comment: The top voted (so far) answer is a HHGG reference, and there are a few others as well - also "So Long and thanks for all the fish!" was posted as a comment to the question. Although I didn't down vote, I imagine seeing the same references all over the place it gets old soon.

Answer (score -4):

```
if (i % 15 == 0) printf("FizzBuzz");  // think about why we have to ask 
                                      //     people to write FizzBuzz.
```

Answer (score -4):

Cue groaning...

```
while(true) 
     points += answerQuestion();   // Symbolic gesture
```

Answer (score -4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) { /* Cause two is
  a[i].aye();                       one two many */
}
```

Comment: You’ve commented out your own code.

Answer (score -5):

Technically a one-liner

```
array_walk(
    array('your mom\'s bedroom', 'a bar with a lawyer and a clown', 'kansas'),
    function (&$mordor) { 
        echo 'One does not simply walk into '.$mordor.".\n"; // OH YEAH!?
    }
);
```

Answer (score -6):

```
my_problem=["stuck","under","flow"]
print '! '.join(my_problem)+ "! " # if you are pitying
```

Comment: I'm discovering my reputation cannot be negative. Good news!!

Answer (score -8):

What about...

```
<html><body><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></body></html>
```

Going for more generic / less niche than C.

Comment: How is C niche?

Comment: This is *really* boring. You also misspelled "Stack Overflow".

Comment: @Tibor, C isn't niche, but HTML is waaaaaay more generic than C, right? I know people how can even cout but can't printf, and HTML is known even to my 14 yo system-in-law.

Answer (score -8):

```
puts("Press any key to continue...");
while(Key == AnyKey)
{
    Misery++; //No escape from misery..
}
```

Comment: Worse tone than the suicide note.

Answer (score -9):

I'll go with this:

```
printf("MPAA can see this 09F911029D74E35BD84156C5635688C0");  /* However, the
     Compiler can't see this */
```