# Will Meta change to Summer Loving as well?

Tags: discussion, summer-of-love

I've been reading up on the Summer of Love blog posts, with the latest being "hunting of the snark". Though, if one is to make a change in comments and phrasing to *welcome* new users, shouldn't the place where users come for *help* reflect that as well?

Comment: Why does that have to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: This *has* to be a place for debate, period. If a friendliness requirement destroys that, there's no point in Meta being a place to discuss site policy. However as Flexo notes, I don't see these being mutually exclusive. Civil does not mean "I have to agree with you"

Comment: Are you addressing something specific? Even the tired old off-topic questions of new users or of those circumventing a ban usually end up getting a couple of instructive comments. True, debate can perhaps get quite opinionated and somewhat heated, but not to an extent that goes too far IMO.

Comment: Meta is the place you go to die. And you'd want to feel the burn of a thousand suns entering your neck and ear holes instead of having a pillow smothered over your face while sleeping. Well, depends on how you want to go.

Comment: You can't feel the sheer love that Meta simply *radiates*?

Comment: @random That depends on whether you [write your suicide note in C](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142099/what-formatting-example-should-replace-his-suicide-note-in-the-markdown-help) or not!

Comment: Welcome to THE WINTER OF HATE now exclusively on Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: The blog post: *[Kicking off the Summer of Love](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)* (2012-07-20)