# Why are heavily downvoted answers not dimmed if the question is locked?

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-questions

[The popular question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142099/what-formatting-example-should-replace-his-suicide-note-in-the-markdown-help?page=3&tab=votes#tab-top) about improving a Markdown help formatting example has just been locked.
<sub>*(Disclaimer: I have no problem with that, it was a fun and IMHO efficient way to solve that very specific issue, but still technically a code contest.)*</sub>

As you can see from the link above, answers whose scores are `-3` or lower are not dimmed anymore, although of course they used to be before the question was locked.

Is this behavior by design? For consistency with non-locked questions, I think it would be better to keep these answers dimmed.

Comment: Great question, but -1 because I disagree.  I like how it does not dim the low score answers on locked posts and I would not like to see it changed.

Comment: @chown, do you mean you like the exception to the rule, or that you would also get rid of the dimming on unlocked questions?

Comment: I like the exception to the rule.  I think un-locked posts should still dim low score answers.

Comment: @chown why? It's a very odd inconsistency to have

Comment: I should have qualified that I like it for Meta only (for SO I agree that there should be dimming on all <-3 score answers regardless of the questions locked status).  But, for Meta, I feel that answers with downvotes are no less significant then other answers, they just aren't as popular.  I personally still like to see them just as clearly as answers with 150 upvotes.

Comment: @chown That's not the issue here, the problem is that the historical lock leads to inconsistent behaviour. Whether the normal behaviour (on Meta) is to dim the answers or not is a completely different discussion, but locking shouldn't affect the normal behaviour (whatever that is).

Comment: To further clarify, I would prefer if dimming answers didn't exist on *meta* **at all**.  Thats what I mean't as being the exception to the rule; I think I misunderstood when I first commented.

Comment: @chown There was a recent Meta discussion on that, went looking for it but couldn't find it (could have been a comment discussion), how about posting that as a [feature-request]? I don't agree that we shouldn't dim answers on Meta, but I do see the logic of having a larger dimming threshold, something like -8 / -10.

Comment: Everything should be turned ice blue to indicate that everything is frozen and cannot be changed.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn with little icicles hanging off the bottom border, and snow falling from the header

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we pulled the styling for a post, we were only handling a single class for a post.  The first one it hit would be the only one used.

I've changed this up so that multiple special stylings can be used on a single post.

You can see this now with [this example post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142107/140548).

Comment: Thank you for the fix and the explanation :)