# Am I allowed to bounty for other reasons?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I added a bounty to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646851/561731) stating:

> The bounty will go to the best implementation of a right click jQuery plugin.
>
> Preferably one to add/remove right click events from a selector with ease.

Some people are telling me in the [JS Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) that it is an *illegal bounty*.

Is this true?

Am I not allowed to spend my own rep the way I want to?

Comment: It reads like the bounty equivalent of a "give me teh codez" or rent-a-coder question. I'm not sure I particularly like it.

Comment: @Bart yes, but I dont really get anything out of it -- [see this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143473/am-i-allowed-to-bounty-for-other-reasons/143477#comment407918_143477)

Comment: [see this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646851/jquery-right-click-event#comment15926434_1646851) for the more relevant reason to just merge the two questions and be done with it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not so sure on the "illegal", but I would certainly go for a strong "not recommended".

Comment: @Bart "abusive" is the word I'd chose.

Comment: @YannisRizos Perhaps. Its feels a bit like "Well done, you've found a loop-hole. Now please stop doing that".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Are you serious?**

You've turned an old (2009) question into a "give me teh codez" poll and you are wondering why people don't like it? If you felt the question lacked a canonical answer, you could have set a bounty asking for just that, however your bounty message was:

> The bounty will go to the best implementation of a right click jQuery plugin.

...on a question that didn't even mention looking for a plugin:

> in jquery is there a way to distinguish left and right clicks ?

Your bounty was abusive, you brought the wrong kind of attention to an old question. Certainly it's your reputation, and you may spend it in any way want, except ways that are abusive to the community and its rules & guidelines.

Comment: I have noticed people over the recent months upvoting my answer and adding over 200 updates to the fiddle I posted trying to make a good plugin. I assumed it would be helpful to future users to have one place where they can get a good solution to their problem.

Comment: @amanaP: "I assumed it would be helpful to future users to have one place where they can get a good solution to their problem." The proper way to do that is *not* to hijack someone else's question with a bounty. Changing the nature of the question is *not* something a bounty should do. If you want to create a canonical reference for a jQuery plugin to solve this particular issue, then you should ask and answer a question to provide it.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, but If I ased a question like that, it would be closed as "not constructive"

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA If you are aware of that, I wonder why you're surprised your bounty was removed... Bounties are not loop holes / excuses for unsuitable questions.

Comment: @amanaP: If so, then that's pretty strong evidence that Stack Overflow is *not* where such information belongs. SO is not the 1-stop-shop for all programming info and problems.

Comment: I think people are overreacting on this one, maybe not in content but in tone.

Comment: @Pekka Perhaps, I already deleted my answer once (I thought it was a bit charged, and perhaps more suitable as a comment). But Neal is a 40K user, I never thought I'd have to explain this to someone so familiar with the site.

Comment: @Pekka they seem to do that a lot with me... I really do not understand why..... **RAGE QUIT** time?....

Answer (score 13):

> Am I not allowed to spend my own rep the way I want to?

No.

Bounties were originally *very* restrictive, because the intent **wasn't** to turn this into some weird "pay to play" site. When [they were improved and expanded](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/), there were still rules in place to restrict abuse and discourage this "rep as currency" attitude, while the ability to use them was made flexible enough for a much larger set of purposes.

However, with the introduction of custom bounty annotations, I've seen a few situations where a bounty is used to *change the question*. This is bad, for two reasons:

- The bounty message goes away once the bounty expires. You really shouldn't put anything in a bounty message that's needed to understand the question or its answers.
- If you don't own the question, and especially if there are existing answers, you're effectively **making an edit that no one can roll back**. That's crap.

I see a moderator has already refunded this bounty, and I support this decision wholeheartedly. If the answers to that question don't answer *your* question, then you should **ask another question.** Don't abuse the bounty system to change other people's posts.

Comment: .... You of all people [should not talk about misusing the bounty system....](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142099/155556) _please_....

Comment: You're comparing a post that I *edited* after it was posted, two days before adding a bounty, to one that sat on the site for three years before you slapped a bounty on it asking for something tangential? I'd say that yet again you're struggling to recognize the subtle nuances of the situation, but this isn't even nuanced - that you even had to ask this question after folks pointed out the issues with your bounty demonstrates a hard-headed refusal to *listen to folks who are trying to help*. You're better off spending less time pretending to be confused and more time honestly trying to learn.

Answer (score 10):

I've removed the bounty. From your bounty notice:

> The bounty will go to the best implementation of a right click jQuery plugin.

That's not valid for two reasons.  First, it's not constructive, and you are the one that's arbitrating the decision of what the "best" is, in that only *you* can award that bounty.

Second, it's a "gimme teh codez" request.  What is the *actual* problem you're facing?  From your statement, there isn't one, it just reads that you are either a) lazy or b) trying to foster a code competition with rules set by you, neither of which is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

To answer your question, no, you aren't allowed to spend your rep *any* way you see it.  We're actually pretty liberal with allowing you to spend your rep how you want (downvotes, bounties) but it still has to work within the general guidelines of the site.

This all leads to the question of why you did it in the first place?

What is it you're *really* trying to accomplish with the bounty, and what is wrong with the most upvoted, accepted answer that it doesn't suit your needs?  If you elaborate on *that* in the bounty reason, then it would have a much greater chance of attracting the right kind of attention to the question.

Comment: That's a dangerous precedent to set. Asking for a "canonical answer" is ultimately no different than this "best". In the general case at least; this *particular* request is asking for code-only-answers, which would infect the question with crappy answers. So I understand why you removed it, but it is dipping towards... unpleasant territory. If I don't feel the answers are "canonical" enough, and you do, does this mean that you can remove my bounty?

Comment: @Nicol: asking for a better answer - or more "canonical" answer - is fine, assuming the existing answers really don't stack up. Asking for an answer to a question that wasn't asked is something else entirely. Piggybacking on someone else's question because you don't feel like you can write your own question constructively... That's now delving into abuse.