# Markdown editing help code example doesn't preserve the spaces

Tags: bug, markdown, editing-help

The [Markdown editing help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) currently leads with this code example:

> ```
> printf("%d\n", 42);  /* What was the
>  question again? */
> ```

(This quote excludes the four highlighted spaces at the start of each line.)

Obviously, this example comes from [the winning answer to a contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142464/879265), by [Frédéric Hamidi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164403/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric-hamidi). But it is not quite the same. The answer says:

> ```c
> printf("%d\n", 42);  /* What was the
>                         question again? */
> ```

This specific spacing was [added in an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/142464/2) (by the answer’s original author) with this description:

> Ah, silly me, this is supposed to teach how whitespace works in code blocks. Better keep demonstrating fixed-width alignment, then.

It also reflects the previous example (given in the contest question):

> ```
> printf("goodbye world!");  /* his suicide note
>                               was in C */
> ```

The Markdown help page should preserve the spaces used in the answer.

Comment: It comes from a bug. The correct spacing is in the source code but our Markdown parser is stripping it out for whatever reason.