# You can reward a great answer with bounties, but how do you reward a good question?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions)

The best idea I have is looking at the asker's profile, picking a random answer they posted, and give a bounty to that. Is there a better way?

OK This is what I'm thinking: If I see a user asking a great question, I want to quickly reward this guy/girl with more privileges by giving them tons of rep. Is this a bad idea? Why?

Comment: Other than upvoting the question you like, nope.

Comment: I see. I wish I could put bounties to questions :( Time to make ten shadow accounts :)

Comment: If you do, please tell us here exactly what those shadow accounts are. Makes things a lot easier for the mods. ;)

Comment: Or they could just let me put a +500 on a question >:(

Comment: That almost makes me curious enough to ask what this brilliant star of a question is...

Comment: You'll need to fly up to it and see it for yourself :)

Comment: OK This is what I'm thinking: If I see a user asking a great question, I want to quickly reward this guy/girl with more privileges by giving them tons of rep. Is this a bad idea? Why?

Comment: You could post about the question on Reddit or Twitter I suppose.

Comment: To me the whole issue is perhaps rather a definition thing than that I'm utterly opposed to a rep bounty for questions. To me, good answers get awarded rep points. Good questions get awarded good answers. I don't directly see a need to change that situation.

Comment: The reason this isn't possible is because Stack Exchange feels that you should [optimize for pearls, not sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). Questions are the sand that makes the pearls. Answers, not questions, are what the system is all about.

Comment: @gobernador thanks for your answer. I totally forgot about that blog post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think people ask questions for the reputation.  Mostly people are looking for a good answer.  If you want to reward a great question, the best thing you can do is answer it.  If that great question is already answered and you still want to reward the OP, you can go through that person's profile and find an unanswered question that they've asked and answer (or place a bounty on) that one.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But considering there are so many bad questions, I think rewarding good questions is not a bad idea. If OP has collected enough reputation, he can use it for bounty.

Comment: But for democracy reasons, every user is treated in same way. If using only your one vote is not enough, you can spread this question that it gets more attention - and might receive more upvotes.