# Award a bounty to a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, bounties

Suppose I'm helped from a question and would like to gift some points +100 to that question. There is the option to award a bounty to the answer in anyone's question. But I want to award some bounty to the question itself : it's different. So it should say gift rather than bounty. Would you consider adding this feature?

Comment: I think "bounty" is a collective term for anything awarded to someone making (or to make) effort to answer certain questions. If you rename the "bounty" to "gift" it sounds like very "social network" term. I just want to point that out since SE networks is not a social network.=D

Comment: How were you helped by a Question? Was it the question that helped, or the answer to the question?

Comment: @BillWoodger the question....

Comment: Well, not a full answer. But, if the user is "active" and has answered at least one question, you *could* award a bounty on a random answer of theirs, fully explained with a comment on the question and on the answer the bounty is awarded to (so that it does not confuse future readers). Don't know if the "site people" would like it, so wait a bit to see if I get clobbered about it :-)

Comment: @CodyGray anyway my question is little different than your provided question. In  that question saying to bounty for question which confuses mostly but my thinking is to set `gift`

Comment: So, your question is different because you want to call it a "gift", rather than a "bounty"? Sorry, I don't think that's an important difference. If you'd rather, call it "twin" question rather than a "duplicate".

Comment: Interesting twist that was mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280045/152859) is to have expired bounties go to the question. This does make this suggestion unique since it's not about manually giving the bounty. @Cody what do you think? (since OP is long gone, we can edit it in, and reopen.)

Comment: @shadow If it's a new idea, I'm not sure what the advantage would be of editing it in here and reopening. Why don't either you or the other guy ask a new question?

Comment: @Cody because it's really related to this one here, with small tweak. Will leave it for now, might re-think it at some point.