# How to reward a particularly good question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I can post a bounty if I want to reward an existing answer. But what if it was question itself what helped me? I recently stumbled upon a question that alerted me to a problem I wasn't aware of. Quite possibly it saved me hours of pointless work. I can't reward it with a bounty as it would go to the answer, not the question (and it was me who answered it anyway).

Is a single upvote (and maybe clicking "favourite") the only way I can reward the OP's good eye for potential problems?

Note that this is not a feature request or anything. I just want to know, not to change the way things are.

Comment: It's not *much* more than an upvote, but a *favorite* sure feels nice as well.

Comment: Not sure if it's the 'right' thing to do, but last time that happened to me I sought out a particularly good answer the same user had posted, and awarded the bounty on that

Comment: @JoachimSauer done that.

Comment: I read at some point that at least one mod favorite bad questions only to be able to go through them later to see if they have improved.

Comment: @Clive this can work, but it feels wrong. I mean, it almost feels like serial upvoting, only in a bit more acceptable way.

Comment: this actually happened to me .. when you ask question you need to wait and then you will have answer but when you see your question already asked in that case you will get answer immediately  .. i really want to **reward a question(more then upvote)** since the question was exactly what i want to ask and i got the ready to use answer.

Comment: Not sure if it is a duplicate since you are just discussing. But related: [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135469/187824)

Comment: @Mołot Yeah, totally agree. This particular question helped me out loads, and the OP had a bunch of really good answers so it was a straightforward one

Comment: Another thing you can do is to share a link to the question via Fbook/Twitter/G+/etc. If it's a good question more traffic should result in more upvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the question helped you it probably had a good answer to it. You can start a bounty to award that answer.

In this process the question itself gets attention due to the bounty and might get some upvotes from that.

Comment: It was my own answer :P Question saved me a LOT of work by pointing out an irregularity I could investigate instead of assuming I need to upgrade most of my dev machines. Posting answer was kinda a side effect ;)

Comment: @Mołot In that case, how about a thank you note?

Comment: @episanty wouldn't it be " too chatty" comment? ;)

Comment: If it gets deleted then it gets deleted - and they'll have seen it anyway. In these cases I include a brief thank you within the answer, which is unlikely to be edited out (e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70384)).

Answer (score 2):

I like having my questions "favorited" even if I get no points for them.

But we are on a site that operates by points. Therefore, it might make sense to have additional points for "favorites."

My suggestion is to retain the five votes for a question up vote, and have an additional five (or at least three) votes for favoriting. The former would put potential total question reputation at ten points, on par with answers.

Not to say that **every** question should generate ten points of "rep." But IMHO "favorited" ones should, as long as people do so reasonably sparingly, on the honor system.

Comment: Please see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199525/how-to-reward-particulary-good-question#comment-633929).

Comment: @Molot: And I was saying that your "favoriting" should count for something. Perhaps not a disproportionate amount as would be the case for a bounty, but as a "double upvote" if you will. But only in rare cases.

Comment: My point is, and Anders UP provides backup for it, that now favourites are the only way to track posts. There is no way to track bad post to know if it got improved, other than marking it favourite. Adding rep bonus for being faved will remove that option from moderators and other users genuinely trying to help with bad content.

Comment: Favouriting also helps them on their way to the `Stellar Question` and `Favourite Question` badges if they don't already have it.

Comment: @gitsitgo: Good point