# What do you use to mark questions that need editing when you want to avoid excessive bumping?

Tags: discussion, edits, bump, bookmarks

As far as I can tell, on many sites there is a consensus that it is better to avoid [bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bump/info) too many questions at the same time. (At least on the sites I visit frequently I have seen some discussions about this - of course, depending on the size of the site, there can be a substantial difference in what actually constitutes "bumping too many old questions". There are also some feature requests on this site which seem related to this problem, for example: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567).)

On the other hand, it is quite often relatively easy to find many questions that can be improved by some edit. And there are some situations where large numbers of such questions arise naturally. (To list some examples: A new tag was created and it is being added at least to the old questions most relevant to the topic. A tag with many question is being removed by community effort.)

Typically when a user finds many questions that can be edited, they stop after certain number of questions as not to inconvenience others by filling the frontpage by many old questions. Still, it might be useful to mark somewhere the questions which need editing - to do them later as the "next batch".

I'd imagine that many users have this problem. (At last some discussions I had on per-site-metas and in chat suggests so.) Therefore I thought that some suggestions how to approach this might be useful for users from various Stack Exchange sites.

**Question:** What tools do you use to mark question which you intent to edit in future (possibly with marking also the type of edit.)

Comment: I was not really sure whether this is a suitable question here. (Although I think that many SE users encounter this problem.) If it is not a good fit here, I'd be glad to receive some advice where to ask. (The only other idea I had was to ask on Software Recommendations - which will be probably a more general question, although I am asking mainly in connection with usage on [Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange).)

Answer (score 6):

The solution which for my works is to use the "bookmarking" feature of the browser I use. By doing so, I can organize them in subfolders, add descriptions, etc. And there is no risk anybody comes along and deletes "something" which I found worth bookmarking. Easy, and works in any browser that supports bookmarking.

A completely different approach would be to implement the concept of, what I would call, ***labels*** in any SE site, as I described in [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295913/286501) to "[Should we have to approve ("favorite") a question in order to "bookmark" it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295906/286501)". Here is a partial quote of it:

> Think of a label as similar to favorites, whereas each user is free to "mark" something with such label, but with many more extra facilities, and not only to allow a user to mark selected questions using a boolean variable that is on or off.
>
> **Examples to use such labels:**
>
> - ...
> - Submit an edit suggestion ...
> - ...

Refer to my above mentioned answer for way more details (design specs and other examples).

Answer (score 2):

The Favorite function is a good option for just marking questions. You can't make notes, though.

Even if you use it already for other purposes, there's an option to sort by ['date added'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites&sort=added), so that you can revert back to your old favorites list after the edit operation.

Comment: I thought about this too. (And perhaps some users use favorites for this purpose.) They would be a bit more suitable if some possibility to categorize the favorites was available, as suggested here: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). (Probably I should finally get around to try Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey and then I could try the userscript mentioned in one of the answers: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215).)